# Prevent highlight outside wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

how do i prevent user try highlighting a text and prevent mouse goes outside the `<div>` wrapper?

```
<div id="wrapper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 
</div>

$(function(){
  $('#wrapper').on('mousedown', function(){
    // prevent mouse goes outside the wrapper box, all only highlight inside the wrapper
  });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps use CSS, set the whole page (`body`/`html`) to be unselectable, but for `#wrapper` allow it to be selected? Just a guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting JSFiddle example, not sure if it is what you want though: http://jsfiddle.net/j7x0jxha/

Comment: Hm I can't get it to work in IE, with `-ms-user-select: text` it allows selection of just the `#wrapper` but you can extend the selection outside of the element.